# Is there any way to have embedded scrollable tabs?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-scrollable-tabs

I have a layout in my head that should look like that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UbUN.png

Only part that will be dynamic is the blue one. I don't know the number of tabs that will be created before I load the activity, hence the number is acquired from server (could be either 5 or 24 for all I know).

The bottom buttons should not move when I swipe and the blue area changed.

Currently I have this implemented w/o tabs list using embedded fragment in my activity and gesture listener. There's no good looking transaction animation between fragments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Nick Pakhomov: You can use [PagerTabStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html)

### PagerTabStrip

is intended to be used as a child view of a `ViewPager widget in your XML layout`. ***PagerTabStrip*** is most often used with fragment, which is a convenient way to supply and manage the `Lifecycle of each fragment`.

So here’s how a ViewPager with a PagerTabStrip in it would look like in the layout file:

```
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
 
    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_tab_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:textColor="#fff"
         />
 
 
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Please check this [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) demo . I hope it will helps you .